# Draw horizontal arrows two edge with label

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw horizontal arrows with label as attached?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{tikz} \pagestyle{empty} \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw [-] (0, 0) edge node[above] {0} (5, 0); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style={font=\scriptsize, below}]
  \draw [<->, >={Latex},blue] (-1, 0)node[label]{$-1$} -- (1, 0)node[label]{$+1$};
  \draw[thin, blue] (0, 0.2,0)--(0,-0.2) node[label]{$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there way to align all three labels as same line?

Comment: @RajeshN Two ways: replace `node[label]{$0$};` with `node[label, below=-1mm]{$0$}` or, alternatively, remove all of the `\node[label}{...}` commands and instead place them manually using something like `\foreach \x in {-1,0,1} {\node at(\x,-0.3){\scriptsize$\x$};}`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I got output what I expected.

Comment: @RajeshN Glad this was helpful